# jQuery Validation not working on local server but works in browser

Tags: jquery

everyone! I got the same situation like in post [jQuery Validation not working in server! Works Locally. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223065/jquery-validation-not-working-in-server-works-locally-why)
The difference is that I cant make jsfiddle to work http://jsfiddle.net/AlexInspired/uUmeV/
1)How can I add to jsfiddle resourses that are in my html header :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="cs/screen.css" />

<script src="../lib/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

?
2)I use Firebug to watch what is the problem when runnig my page at local server(cause when opening page in browser through file system everything is ok). And there is error in Firebug:

> TypeError: $.validator is undefined $.validator.setDefaults({

On line 13.
It seems like server locking web resoursers.

Comment: html header resources are:
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="cs/screen.css" 

script src="../lib/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"
script  src="../jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"

Answer (score 0):

1)How can I add to jsfiddle resourses that are in my html header

If you want to add custom files to the JFiddle use headers containing the URL to the js or css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://mywebsite/cs/screen.css" />
<script src="http://mywebsite/lib/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For solving the local/server problem try removing the .. in the source for the js. So try:

```
<script src="/lib/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```